# Order list of files by filename, but keeping path

Tags: bash

I need to order a list of files by file name. Currently I do the ordering like this:

```
» find . -name "*.fixtures.json" | sort
./my_registration/fixtures/0600-my_registration.fixtures.json
./soamgr/fixtures/0200-soamgr.fixtures.json
./soaprj/fixtures/0100-users.fixtures.json
./soaprj/fixtures/0110-permissions.fixtures.json
./soaprj/fixtures/0120-groups.fixtures.json
```

Which is ordering by full path (as expected).

In this case I would like to order just by file name (so that my number prefixes are the ones defining the ordering), *but* keeping the path information. This is the output I would need:

```
./soaprj/fixtures/0100-users.fixtures.json
./soaprj/fixtures/0110-permissions.fixtures.json
./soaprj/fixtures/0120-groups.fixtures.json
./soamgr/fixtures/0200-soamgr.fixtures.json
./my_registration/fixtures/0600-my_registration.fixtures.json
```

Is there an easy way to do this in bash, with standard unix tools?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Append this to your find to use a [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform):

```
| awk -F/  '{print $NF "/" $0}' | sort -n | cut -d / -f 2-
```

Output:

```
./soaprj/fixtures/0100-users.fixtures.json
./soaprj/fixtures/0110-permissions.fixtures.json
./soaprj/fixtures/0120-groups.fixtures.json
./soamgr/fixtures/0200-soamgr.fixtures.json
./my_registration/fixtures/0600-my_registration.fixtures.json
```

---

awk:

> `-F`: sets the field separator
>
> `$NF`: number of fields in the current record / last column
>
> `$0`: whole line of arguments

Comment: This is very clean, I like it. And you gave a name to something that I do all the time!

Answer (score 1):

*If* directory depth is the same for all the files (3 in your example) the following will work:

```
find . -name "*.fixtures.json" | sort -t/ -k 4n
```

Comment: To make it depth independent, you can search for and find the number and prepend it to the line: `find ... | sed 's,.*/\([0-9][0-9]*\)-,\1 &,' | sort -n | cut -d ' ' -f 2-`.

Comment: @thatotherguy thanks for the tip! Seems that the other alternative is to use `awk`, `sort -k` doesn't support negative indexes.

Comment: Depth can in fact vary

Answer (score 1):

If the depth is not fixed you use something like this

```
$ sed 's_.*/_& _' files | sort -k2n | sed 's_/ _/_'

./soaprj/fixtures/0100-users.fixtures.json
./soaprj/fixtures/0110-permissions.fixtures.json
./a/b/c/d/0115-dummy.json
./soaprj/fixtures/0120-groups.fixtures.json
./soamgr/fixtures/0200-soamgr.fixtures.json
./my_registration/fixtures/0600-my_registration.fixtures.json
```

I added a dummy record to verify sorting.  Assumes no spaces in file names or paths.

Comment: Thanks, interesting. The first sed is changing the path separator, right?

Comment: Yes, since sed is greedy it will separate the last path separator from the filename.